# css scrolling too soon

Tags: css

I pretty much got it down packed now. Just a quick thing I want to know how to fix.

I have this post comment button (it scrolls perfectly) however, it scrolls too soon even when you're not even past it's point. Live example:

http://www.krissales.com/#/media/38.Testing-Another-One-Yo

the CSS I have is this:

```
<div style="float:right;position:fixed;right:14%;padding-top:35px;" style="top: 0px;">
      <a href="_lib/forms/comment.php?id=<?php echo $article_id; ?>" class="-button silver" rel="facebox"><span class="-paper">Post Comment</span></a>
 </div>
```

would you guys know how I could go about fixing this? If you still don't understand, basically when I'm at the top of the page, and i scroll just a little, the "post comment" bar moves, I don't want it to move until i get past the area, then it should scroll.

thanks!

Comment: may i know do u want to move the "post comment" btn, if yes, when?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give the button a class and remove inline styles as that is bad practice. Second, create a second class that you'll attach for when you want it fixed. So that you can better understand what I mean, test the following code:

html:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="testBox">test</div>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

css:

```
.box { height:500px; }
.testBox { background-color:#000000; color:#FFFFFF; width:100px; height:30px; }
.textBoxFixed { position:fixed; top:0; }
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (scrollFromTop >= 500) {
            $('.testBox').addClass('textBoxFixed');
        } else {
            $('.testBox').removeClass('textBoxFixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You've got jQuery installed on your site, so I used jQuery. On the jsfiddle link you posted, you were using mootools. Change that selection on the left to the latest version of jQuery and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [link](http://www.anthonymclin.com/code/7-miscellaneous/107-jquery-lockscroll-121), what ou need is a mix between js and css fixed and relative position around the `div` and read (by jquery) when the `div`reach the top